# How to create a loop between the mask and the background image in AS3 when mouseover

Tags: actionscript-3

I am new in AS3, for one of my assignment, I need to modified the existing code(copy paste and modify) to create certain effect. The effect that I need to create is when I MouseOver on the stage, the mask will form a loop with background image and back to normal(mask layer not visible) when I MouseOut of the stage. Here is the code that need to modifly.

```
    var mymask:Sprite=new Sprite();
    var isOver:Boolean=false;
    var spotSize:Number=0;

    pic2.addChild(mymask);
    pic2.mask=mymask;
    pic2.mouseEnabled=false;

    mymask.x=0;
    mymask.y=0;

    function drawSpot(r:Number):void{
        mymask.graphics.clear();
        mymask.graphics.lineStyle(1,0x000000);
        mymask.graphics.beginFill (0x00000F);
        mymask.graphics.drawRect(0,0,r,900);
        mymask.graphics.endFill();

        spotSize=r;
    }


    pic1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, mouseOver);

    function mouseOver(e:MouseEvent):void{

        isOver=true;
    }

    pic1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, mouseOut)

    function mouseOut(e:MouseEvent):void{
        isOver=false;
    }

    stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enter);

    function enter(e:Event):void{
        var cursorSize:Number=spotSize;
        if(isOver==true && cursorSize<1)
        drawSpot(cursorSize+999);
        if(isOver==false && cursorSize>10)
        drawSpot(cursorSize-999);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're trying to animate a circular mask by modifying the code above?
If so, this is the code changes needed.

In your drawSpot method, change the line:
    `mymask.graphics.drawRect(0,0,r,900);`
to:
    `mymask.graphics.drawCircle(pic2.width * .5, pic2.height * .5, r);`

Then in your enter method,

```
function enter(e:Event):void{
    var cursorSize:Number=spotSize;
    if(isOver==true && cursorSize<999)
    drawSpot(cursorSize+1);
    if(isOver==false && cursorSize>0)
    drawSpot(cursorSize-1);

}
```

What you're doing is saying IF the mouse is over and the cursorSize is less than the full value (you had 999 before so I kept that) then increment the size by 1. It will keep doing this every frame until the size is 999 or higher (or the mouse is no longer over).

If the mouse isn't over and the mask isn't 0 in size, it will decrease the size by 1 every frame until it's 0 or less.

If you want it to go faster, simply change the +1 and -1 to a higher number

Comment: And, Rather than doing cursorSize<999,  it would be better to use cursorSize < Math.max(pic1.width, pic1.height).   That way it doesn't get bigger than necessary (the size of the height or width of the picture it's masking - whichever is bigger)